# Seconds since epoch to relative date

Tags: python, time, epoch

I'm working with dates since epoch, and already got, for example:

```
date = 6928727.56235
```

I'd like to transform this into another relative format, so that I'll be able to transform this into something relative to epoch.

Using time.gmtime(date), it returned

```
year=1970, mon=3, day=22, hour=4, min=38, sec=47
```

I think epoch starts in '01/01/1970 00:00:00',  so the method should return the relative date in something like:

```
'2 months 21 days 04:38:47'
```

Anything that help?

Comment: 22-March 04:38 is not 2 months 22 days 04:38 after 01-January 00:00.

Comment: No, it is actually 2 months 21 days 04:38:47...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from datetime import timedelta

a = timedelta(seconds=6928727.56235)

# a is now datetime.timedelta(80, 16727, 562350)

print "%d days %02d:%02d:%02d" % (a.days, a.seconds / 3600, (a.seconds / 60) % 60, a.seconds % 60)
```

Returns `80 days 04:38:47`, which is correct, but not exactly what OP wanted (80 days instead of 2 months 21 days).

Comment: Thank you. This solution is enough to me.

Answer (score 5):

> The method should return the relative
>   date in something like:
>   '2 months 22 days 04:38:47'

You can't do that, since a month is between 28 and 31 days long. The statement "2 months and 22 days" could mean anything between 81 and 84 days. (Or between 78 and 84 days, if the months doesn't have to be consecutive).

So what you want is simply nonsensical. A relative date time can only be counted in days, hours and seconds, until the difference becomes so big that the amount of days no longer matters, in which case you can start counting in months or years (but then you can't include days anymore).

So you can say "five years and two months", or "80 days and three hours", or "two hundred years". But you can not say "two months and three days" or "five years and 20 days". The statements simply make no sense.

Therefore, the correct answer is indeed eumiros

```
timedelta(seconds=6928727.56235)
```

But now you also know why.

*(Unless of course, you with month actually mean moon-cycles, which* do *have a fixed length. :))*

Comment: Thank you for this explanation, and I'll think about use it instead of the other syntax ('two months ...'). What you told make sense. Thank you for this add.

Comment: @GabrielL.Oliveira: In general, [a day is not 86400 (SI?) seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20335352/4279) exactly unless we are talking about POSIX time (as implied by your question) that is different from UTC. Therefore "days + seconds + microseconds" makes as much sense as "months + days" i.e., you can use them if you can ignore (in your particular case) the difference between 86400 and 86401 (million microseconds) or 28 and 31 (three days) correspondingly.

Comment: You can say "two months and three days" if it is known (by convention) to mean the difference between two specific dates (which indeed can be anything between 81 and 84 days), for example the difference between the desired date and start of epoch.

Answer (score 1):

time.gmtime returns a ParseTuple object and you can use the individual elements of the tuple do your calculation. Something like this

```
>>> time_epoch = time.gmtime(0)
>>> time_at_hand = time.gmtime(6928727.56235)
>>> print "It's been %d days somewhat like  %d months, %d days and %d hours, %d  minutes, %d seconds " % (time_at_hand.tm_yday - time_epoch.tm_yday, time_at_hand.tm_mon - time_epoch.tm_mon , time_at_hand.tm_mday - time_epoch.tm_mday, time_at_hand.tm_hour - time_epoch.tm_hour, time_at_hand.tm_min - time_epoch.tm_min, time_at_hand.tm_sec - time_epoch.tm_sec)
It's been 80 days somewhat like  2 months, 21 days and 4 hours, 38  minutes, 47 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Eumiro's Answer, but no need to divide by 60 etc - instead, use `Pandas` Timestamp and take the difference from beginning of epoch.

```
date = 6928727.56235
import pandas as pd
pd.Timestamp(datetime.fromtimestamp(date))-pd.Timestamp(datetime.fromtimestamp(0))
```

returns

```
Timedelta('80 days 04:38:47.562350')
```