# python: convert year/month/day/hour/min/second to # seconds since Jan 1 1970

Tags: python, datetime, time, epoch

I know how to do it in C and Java, but I don't know a quick way of converting year/month/day/hour/min/second to the # of seconds since the Jan 1 1970 epoch.

Can someone help me?

So far I've figured out how to create a [`datetime` object](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) but I can't seem to get the elapsed # seconds since the epoch.

(edit: my question is the inverse of this other one: [Python: Seconds since epoch to relative date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693915/python-seconds-since-epoch-to-relative-date))

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `timetuple` or `utctimetuple` method to get time tuple and convert it to timestamp using `time.mktime`

```
>>> import datetime
>>> dt = datetime.datetime(2011, 12, 13, 10, 23)
>>> import time
>>> time.mktime(dt.timetuple())
1323793380.0
```

There is a nice bug related to it http://bugs.python.org/issue2736, this is interesting read and anybody trying to convert to timestamp should read this. According to that thread correct way is

```
timestamp = (dt - datetime(1970, 1, 1)) / timedelta(seconds=1)
```

Comment: `mktime()` works only if `dt` is a local time. "correct way" works only if `dt` is a naive datetime object that represents time in UTC (it is wrong if `dt` is a local time). See [Converting datetime.date to UTC timestamp in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8778548/4279).

Answer (score 7):

You can use `datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1)` as a reference and get the total amount of seconds from a `datetime.timedelta` object as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime

delta = your_date - datetime(1970, 1, 1)
delta.total_seconds()
```

Comment: it assumes that `your_date` is UTC date.

Answer (score 3):

```
import calendar

calendar.timegm(datetime_object.utctimetuple())
```

Comment: `utctimetuple()` fails silently if `datetime_object` has no timezone info attached unless `datetime_object` is already represents UTC time.

Answer (score 1):

These lines can return a float number representing seconds since epoch.

```
import time

time.time()
```

Answer (score 1):

To convert a datetime object (broken-downtime time: year/month/day/hour/min/second) to  [seconds since the Epoch (POSIX time)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xbd_chap04.html#tag_21_04_15):

```
seconds_since_epoch = datetime_object.timestamp()
```

Note: [POSIX Epoch is "00:00:00 GMT, January 1, 1970"](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xbd_chap03.html#tag_21_03_00_17).

If `datetime_object` has no timezone info then `.timestamp()` method uses a local timezone.

[`datetime.timestamp()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp) is introduced in Python 3.3; for code that works on older Python versions, see [Converting datetime.date to UTC timestamp in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8778548/4279).